# for in loop over list (with +=) coding beginner

Tags: python, for-in-loop

```
a = [1,2,3]
for num in a:
  a = a + [num]
print(a)

>>>[1,2,3,1,2,3]
```

---

```
a = [1,2,3]
for num in a:
  a += [num]
print(a)

>>>
```

The first code works as expected, so I assume the below code will work the same, but it didn't print anything. Not even a Error message.

Question:
I did some research in stackoverflow on the use of +=, but still got confused on what's the difference between the **add** and **iadd**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case, you are rebinding the name `a` to a new value, so the variable `a` before the loop is not the same object as the variable `a` inside and after the loop.  The loop is able to iterate on the *original* value of `a`.

But in the second case, you are not rebinding the name.  `a` is the same object throughout the code.  And so the loop iterates over a list that grows endlessly bigger.

Comment: Thanks! I also used the Thonny app to debug, and it shows exactly what you said! The a with the same name is no longer the original a any more!